# How can I keep simplelogger.properties used by SLF4j SimpleLogger file at some system path rather keeping it in classpath?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, slf4j-api

Is it possible to put simplelogger.properties used by SLF4j SimpleLogger file at some system path rather keeping it in classpath i.e. src/main/resources?

I have gone through the SLF4j SimpleLogger documentation but couldn't find any reference to my requirement.

Is there any SYSTEM property which could be set?